# Forcefully delete Home Page of a site programatically

Tags: feature, site, sitepages

I want to delete the Site page which is set as home page. Now I have created a feature and on deactivating it the Site page is deleted. But I am facing the error as follows :

> The item that you are trying to delete is the current welcome page and cannot be deleted.

As this is a home page so it doesn't allowing me to delete it. But I want to delete it.

Is there any way to delete forcefully (Programmatically)

Any help would e appreciated

Comment: Add a new page, set it as welcome page. Then delete the old page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty much self explanatory. You need to set a different page as welcome page first and then delete your current welcome page.

Try and modify below code as per you requirement:

```
using (SPSite oSiteCollection = new SPSite("https://sitecollectionurl"))
{
    //change as per your spweb 
    SPWeb rootWeb = oSiteCollection.RootWeb;
    SPFolder rootFolder = rootWeb.RootFolder; 
    //change welcome page to a different page, ensure path is correct
    rootFolder.WelcomePage = "default.aspx"; 
    rootFolder.Update();


    SPFile oldHomePage = rootWeb.GetFile("url of page to be deleted");
    oldHomePage.Delete();
    rootWeb.Dispose();
}
```